# How to get the request body returned in cold fusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

Here's the link for response.

http://requestb.in/116o44e1?inspect

From this response,I have to get the 'RAW BODY'.For that I have tried like this in Cold Fusion.

```
<cfhttp url="http://requestb.in/116o44e1?inspect" method="get">
<cfset getResult =(cfhttp.filecontent.RAW BODY)>
<cfoutput>#getResult#</cfoutput>
```

But It doesn't works. How to do this in correct manner.Please help me on this.

This is the error while I am trying to get the value:

[image: Error]

Comment: anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Do you intend to extract the content in `<div class="request-body"...` of the response?

Comment: @Alex No, how to do this bro...could you explain it?

Comment: @Beginner , Now I edit the question.please take a look.

Comment: "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members."  now it shows this error bro..

Comment: @jsaonboo  The response returned is of type `text/html` so, `cfhttp.filecontent` is of type `String`. I think you are expecting `application/json` here?

Comment: yes it is not possible to get value like this?

Comment: Take things one step at a time.  Step 1, do a dump of the cfhttp variable and look at the name of all available variables.

Comment: `cfhttp.filecontent` is the 'body' of the result. Do this and let us know the results: `<cfhttp url="http://requestb.in/116o44e1?inspect" method="get"><cfdump var="#cfhttp#">`

Answer (score 1):

In your image on line 696, you are setting it like this:

```
<cfset getresult = (cfhttp.filecontent.raw body)>
```

This is incorrect syntax.

Try this:

```
<cfhttp url="http://127.0.0.1" method="get" >

 <!--- this will return the content of your url --->
<cfset getresult=cfhttp.fileContent>
```

Let me know if that helps.